# PIP install version problems on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, requirements

I am trying to install several dependencies for a python project from a requirements.txt file.

When it encounters the "torch" dependency, it claims to be unable to find version 1.3.1 -- but only on my Mac and not on Ubuntu, which is puzzling. (using a different version like 1.4 is not an option for this project, unfortunately)

On my Mac:

```
➜  code mkdir test_proj
➜  code cd test_proj
➜  test_proj mkvirtualenv $(basename $(pwd))
created virtual environment CPython3.8.5.final.0-64 in 304ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/aeb/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.2, setuptools==49.6.0, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/get_env_details
(test_proj) ➜  test_proj which python
/Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/python
(test_proj) ➜  test_proj which pip
/Users/aeb/.virtualenvs/test_proj/bin/pip
(test_proj) ➜  test_proj pip install torch==1.3.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.1
(test_proj) ➜  test_proj
```

Interestingly, within an Ubuntu VM, there is no issue with the same pip install command:

```
user@devbox-vm2:~$ pip3 install torch==1.3.1
Collecting torch==1.3.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/95/90e8c4c31cfc67248bf944ba42029295b77159982f532c5689bcfe4e9108/torch-1.3.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

Does anyone **know why the mac version of pip is having trouble finding this specific version of PyTorch, but Ubuntu is not having the same problem** and completes successfully?

Perhaps more to the point, **is there a way to "point" the Mac version of pip to the same package file that the Ubuntu VM** is using, since that seems to be working (or an analogous **modification I can make to the requirements.txt file so that it works on Mac**, and not just on Ubuntu)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch` 1.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.3.1/#files) doesn't provide wheels for Python 3.8 so your Python on Mac cannot install it. On Ubuntu you use Python 3.6 so `pip` on Ubuntu can install this version.

Use Python 3.6 or 3.7 on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the [list of files available](https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.3.1/#files) for that version of Torch, you can see that:

- There is no source distribution (which would generally be a `.tar.gz`) version that you would be able to recompile;
- All available binary distributions target either:

  - `manylinux1` is a tag that works on many linux versions, that can be pretty old - it is not surprising that it would work on Ubuntu, with Python 2.7, 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7;
  - Mac OS 10.6 with Python 3.5, or Mac OS 10.7 with Python 2.7, 3.6, or 3.7 - these builds would probably work on later versions of Mac OS, provided the version of Python matches;

In particular, none of these distributions can run on Python 3.8, which is the version of Python shown by your console output.